# Listbox: "could not set the columnWidths property type mismatch"

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a very simple code for a listbox, but once in a while, specially when moving the workbook to a new computer I get the error  "could not set the columWidths property type mismatch"
If I save the workbook and reopen everything works fine while opening the user form. What could be causing it? Thanks!

```
        .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 17
        .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
    
        .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "18,50,80,60,60,40,43,40,44,38,45,35,43,40,95,60,559"
        
        If iRow > 1 Then
        
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Crypto!A2:Q" & iRow
        Else
        
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Crypto!A2:Q2"
            
        End If
```

Comment: Have you tried setting ColumnWidths after setting the RowSource?

Comment: Have you tried using semi-colons instead of commas? [ColumnWidths property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/columnwidths-property)

Comment: It is the commas. I just don't know why after saving it works again. But with semi-colons worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: @braX that is really cool and you're a genius! It happened to me exactly the same, I changed colons to semicolons and it worked fine.
However a big doubt remains, as I can assure that before that it also worked several times fine, with the colons. I can't find what could be changed to change that behavior; but it is certainly that those things make me feel that MS VBA has certain alarming "random reactions", sometimes...

Comment: @Guille it's a regional setting, so it's going to depend on what country/region you have your computer set up to use.

Comment: And for the record, this is a comma `,` and this is a colon `:` and this is a semi-solon `;`

Answer (score 0):

```
.lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "18;50;80;60;60;40;43;40;44;38;45;35;43;40;95;60;559"
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?